# Can you verify a property setter using mockk?

Tags: kotlin, verify, mockk

We had a few tests in Java and Mockito, which we are progressively converting into Kotlin and Mockk. There's a problem, though. This simple line:

`verify(mockedInteractor).setIndex(1);`

When we move it to mockk, we get this:

`verify { mockedInteractor.index = 1 }`

This of course passes the tests, as it's not actually checking that `index` was set to 1. It's simply setting the mock's variable to 1. This below has the same effect.

`verify { mockedInteractor.setIndex(1) }`

Is there a way to verify setters?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try capture:

```
val fooSlot = slot<String>()
val mockBar = mockk<Bar>()
every { mockBar.foo = capture(fooSlot) } answers { }
assertEquals(fooSlot.captured, "expected")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!
You can also use 'just runs' in place of empty answers: `every { mockBar.foo = capture(fooSlot) } just runs`

Comment: Here's the Mockk documentation on verifying functions which return Unit, including @BrunoPereira's comment about using `just Runs`. https://mockk.io/#returning-unit

Answer (score 11):

I'm wondering if this was asked about an earlier version of Mockk, afterall, it *is* and old question.

```
verify { mockedInteractor.index = 1 }
```

does exactly what it says - it verifies that `mockedInteractor.index` was set to `1`.
If you don't believe me, try it. Try setting `mockedInteractor.index` to something other than `1` in the product code and watch this test fail.

Maybe this was a Mockk bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Nice, confirmed this works as expected. Did a "red light / green light" test, making sure it fails if the value is wrong. This should be the accepted answer now

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can:

```
verify { mockedInteractor setProperty "index" value 1 }
```

There are more examples in here https://mockk.io/#private-functions-mocking--dynamic-calls

Answer (score 7):

Compact solution without hardcoded string:

```
verify { mockedInteractor setProperty MockedInteractor::index.name value 1 }
```

where `MockedInteractor` is `mockedInteractor` class

Answer (score 1):

You can now relax this requirement for unit functions when defining your mock.

```kotlin
val foo = mockk<Foo>(relaxUnitFun = true)
```

Enabling this setting on your mock means you will not need to use `justRun` or any variation of that code (as per the [Mockk documentation](https://mockk.io/#returning-unit)) when verifying unit functions are invoked.